# String Operation in Java string assigned with XML

Tags: java, xml, regex

I have a string variable in Java code which assigned by below XML.

```
<note>
<to>Joy</to>
<from>Jaquie</from>
<heading>
Reminder email about product <a id="123" title ="product serial number 123"></a> </heading>
<body>Don't  forget to see the webURL <a id="123" title ="product serial number 123"> this a very useful product</a> and also see this product <a id="245"  title="product serial number 245"> this is certainly useful product</a></body>
</note>
```

and  I have an API method which returns a custom title corresponding to id of the
  tags.

```
public String CustomTitle(String id) {

  -----
  -----
  -----
  return " This is custom title for this web url";
}
```

Now in the above XML I have to replace the title of  tags  which reside in the  and  with new custumTitle returned by above API method.

I think somewhere I may require to use regular expression or some complex JAVA string operation.

Could somebody help me on this.

NOTE - I am newbie in JAVA and SAXParser and DOM are also new for me. i am stuck in some crtical prodution issue so could you please provide code for my problem .

Comment: You need an XML parser.

Comment: @SLaks Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: "could you please provide code for my problem" -- I'm sorry you're stuck in a critical production issue, but please understand: this site doesn't exist to do your work for you.  If you're stuck in a critical production issue, and don't know how to write a solution, you better let your manager know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into `SAXParser` It lets you know when you enter a particular tag in `XML`.
Then, while inside the tag, it will give you the data in the tag. It will also let you know when you are outside the tag (tag has ended).
Tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Other parsers are `DOM` and `StAX`.
`DOM` is used when you need an in-memory tree representation of your XML document and then you can get particular nodes using `XPath` expressions.
Stax is `Streaming API for XML`. You need this when you need to stream data over the wire.

If you are feeling a little adventurous, look into `JAXB`. JAXB allows you to map your XML directly to a class file.
Detailed tutorials by Blaise Doughan: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html

Comment: I  am newbie in JAVA and SAXParser and DOM are also new for me. i am stuck in some crtical prodution issue so could you please provide code  for my problem . I will certainly learn these stuff soon.

Comment: @Joy At least you should not have used your real name if you were posting about work here. Sorry to say but I am no expert either. `SAXParser` is really really easy. Just have a look at the code. It shouldn't take you more than a couple of hours worth of work to get things rolling.

Comment: Thanks a lot Little child.

Comment: @Joy The logic in `SAX` is : "Oh, I am in `<from>` tag? Better get ready to store the data". And when you get the data. "Let me store it in !". After that, done :)